# GetElementByID.GetElementsByTagName returns null

Tags: c#, xml, list

My friend wrote this piece of XML code for simple testing in our game when it comes to loading and writing save data. The problem is that his code does not work at all and I have never wrote any piece of XML code before so this is new for me and I decided to learn XML.
All it wants is the x and y values to create a new Tile object.
When running the code it gives the error:

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled

HResult=-2147467261

Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

TL;DR It loads simple Tiles and all it's looking for is the x and y position to later add to a list that is accessed in the Level class.

The code he wrote:

```
public class XmlHandler
{
    private List<Base.Tile> tiles;
    public XmlHandler()
    {
    }
    public void Load()
    {
        XmlDocument documentFile = new XmlDocument();
        documentFile.Load(@"C:\Tiles\0.xml");

        var listOfTiles = documentFile.GetElementById("tiles").GetElementsByTagName("tile");

        foreach(XmlElement tile in listOfTiles)
        {
            var x = ((XmlElement)tile.GetElementsByTagName("position")[0]).GetAttribute("x");
            var y = ((XmlElement)tile.GetElementsByTagName("position")[0]).GetAttribute("y");
            Classes.Base.Tile t = new Base.Tile(new Vector2(float.Parse(x), float.Parse(y)));
            this.tiles.Add(t);
        }
    }
    public List<Base.Tile> GetTiles()
    {
        return this.tiles;
    }
}
```

The current XML file, modified from the original as shown below

```
<tiles>
<tile>
    <position x="10" y="20" />
</tile>
<tile>
    <position x="50" y="20" />
</tile>
<tile>
    <position x="30" y="40" />
</tile>
</tiles>
```

And this is the original XML that I modified because the first line caused errors

```
<?xml encoding="utf-8"?>
<tiles>
<tile>
    <id>1</id>
    <position x="10" y="20" />
</tile>
<tile>
    <id>2</id>
    <position x="50" y="20" />
</tile>
<tile>
    <id>3</id>
    <position x="30" y="40" />
</tile>
</tiles>
```

Thanks for viewing/reading. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The bug is here:

```
var listOfTiles = documentFile.GetElementById("tiles").GetElementsByTagName("tile");
```

Change it this way:

```
var listOfTiles = documentFile.GetElementsByTagName("tiles").GetElementsByTagName("tile");
```

`<tiles>` is a tag and it hasn't got any id.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is the complete class or not, but firstly it looks like you haven't created a list for the tiles.

Somewhere before you start adding tiles to the list 'tiles', you need to write:

tiles = new List();

I suggest the constructor.

It would also be helpful to know where the null reference exception is happening.  Make sure your list is set, and then if the problem still occurs, add a comment and I'll run your code on my machine.

Comment: Stefano is right, but I would suggest using this to file the tiles instead:

documentFile.SelectNodes("//tile");

This returns a list of XmlNodes anywhere in your XML file that are called tile.  It saves you having to get the tiles Element, and then the tiles from there.

Comment: It's not possible to make a new NodeList like that.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx), `GetElementById` will return elements with an id *attribute* as defined in a DTD (or just `id` by default).  You don't have any `id` attributes, so this returns null - hence the exception.

If you change the offending line to this:

```
var listOfTiles = documentFile.GetElementsByTagName("tile");
```

Then your current code will work fine.  However... LINQ to XML is a far cleaner API, you could write your entire method as below:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Tiles\0.xml");

var tiles =
    from tile in doc.Descendants("tile")
    from position in tile.Elements("position")
    let x = (float)position.Attribute("x")
    let y = (float)position.Attribute("y")
    select new Base.Tile(new Vector2(x, y));

this.tiles = tiles.ToList();
```

Comment: This fixed all my problems! Thank you.